Position equation number always on the edge side of the page
Is it possible to switch equation numbers from leqno/reqno depending on whether the page is even or odd? I'd like equation numbers to never appear on the spine side of my twoside memoir document, and always on the edge side (thus alternating).1in

Note that this has nothing to do with memoir. Also not sure if it is possible, as the algorithms are a bit different. Thirdly, I would find it annoying to read of I'm flipping through a book looking for a specific equation

The following code is more like a proof of concept (works only with a few environments from amsmath, equation would require some other idea. The code uses changepage to check if the current page is odd or even. Also, appears that putting equation numbers to the left or to the right in amsmath depends only on one boolean parameter, so I've added a simple hook which sets this parameter at the start of gather, align and multline. The code doesn't work properly if the multiline formula breaks across multiple pages:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\seteqno}{%
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \global\tagsleft@false
  \else
    \global\tagsleft@true
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\AddToHook{env/gather/before}{\seteqno}
\AddToHook{env/align/before}{\seteqno}
\AddToHook{env/multline/before}{\seteqno}

\newcommand{\test}{%
Gather (used for a single equation)
\begin{gather}
  1+1=2.
\end{gather}
Align
\begin{align}
  1+1&=2,\\
  2+2&=4.
\end{align}
Multline
\begin{multline}
  1+1=2,\\
  2+2=4.
\end{multline}
}

\begin{document}
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\end{document}

The output:


That's perfect! Why doesn't it work for equation?
