Label eqn on the left side for even page and label eq on the right side por odd page
is there a way to have the eq label on the left side por even pages and on the right side for odd pages? I believe this would make it easier to read the equations and their corresponding labels.  I am using book for the class document and only the option leqno. Thanks!

It is not, it is really annoying to read when the eq number keeps jumping from page to page like that. Similarly we don't move the number of a section depending on if it is on an odd or even page.

You do not mention explicitly, but I get the feeling you are using LaTeX. I guess one can test with \ifodd also there, it seems to work OK in ConTeXt. But I fear it will break in some cases when the formula run over pages or maybe if they appear at the top.

Hi, many thanks for your quick replay. Yes, I am using LaTex, sorry I didn't mentioned. I am working on a math book and often have large equations which some times get to close to the label. I will try your suggestion \ifodd and see what happens.

Another possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/722743/36296

You wrote, “I believe this would make it easier to read the equations.” What makes you believe that? Speaking for myself, I would detest having to read such a piece.

Thanks for the suggestions. Yes, both suggestion are ok for very simple line equations, but things start getting messing with large block (matrix, and more complicated schemes) at page break. I'll keep trying.
